# When is SU07 form applicable for standard UK visit visa?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I have a friend in the UK who is willing to sponsor my travel to his country. I looked for what documents are needed for him to be able to show sponsorship and how can he and I bring that into consideration in the application.

So far, I've only been able to find the SU07 form. However, there is not enough official information about its applicability and mode of inclusion. Most of the information I find regarding that form seems to hint at its usage by family members to sponsor visits of other family members to the UK.

1. Is the SU07 applicable for family and relatives only?
2. Is it acceptable to include a scanned copy of it filled and signed, along with required documents, or does it needs to be the original form?
3. If this is not meant for sponsorship from a friend, then are there other options?

Comment: I up voted your question as it is ideal for this site. However, you mentioned in another question being sponsored by your parents and now you mention sponsorship from a friend. You should consider getting professional advice because having multiple sponsors can make you look too desperate and still won't change the basic need to show that you have good reason to go home at the end of the visit.

Comment: Although your recent refusal (per your other question) does not indicate under what section(s) you were refused, you may wish to have a [read of this TSE canonical](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) as it addresses your concerns, as @user16259 points out.

Comment: @user16259 well yes i understand what you mean. But at the same time i still need the information regarding the scope of this form and it's mode of application. I do want to seek professional advice but I wonder if there is a official consultation kiosk or something, ran by visa home office as private agencies often have none or outdated info on anything that's not common knowledge?

Comment: The UK government does not, to my knowledge, run such a kiosk. I can only suggest using a licenced legal practitioner rather than a visa agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got my visa granted.

What did I include:

- Scanned copy of filled and signed Su07 form
- Scanned copy of **sponsor's** supporting docs (bills, bank statements
  , house deeds) for Su07
- Scanned copy of sponsor's invitation on his letterhead
- Scanned copy of ticket of an event that I am invited to attend by the
  sponsor

Irrelevant to this question the other docs I included in original were the same I included last time e.g. tax certificate, bank statements , covering letter , profile etc.

However, the last application was rejected so I believe Su07 did had some weight in getting the application granted this time around